# What is wrong about Syntax for the following sql queries?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mariadb

I am new to sql and some of the queries that I wrote give errors. I can not find where the syntax is wrong.

```
String query4 = "SELECT C.cname FROM company C WHERE NOT EXISTS " +
                    "( (SELECT S.sid FROM student S WHERE year = 'freshman') AS temp1 EXCEPT (SELECT A.sid FROM apply A WHERE A.cid = C.cid) AS temp2 )";
```

This query gives: MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS temp1 EXCEPT (SELECT A.sid FROM apply A WHERE A.cid = C.cid) AS temp2 )' at line 1

and

```
"WITH names_and_gpas AS (SELECT sname, cname, gpa FROM student NATURAL JOIN apply NATURAL JOIN company) " +
                    "SELECT cname, AVG(gpa) FROM names_and_gpas GROUP BY cname";
```

This query gives: MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'names_and_gpas AS (SELECT sname, cname, gpa FROM student NATURAL JOIN apply NATU' at line 1

Comment: For SQL 1: remove `AS temp1` and `AS temp2`; the aliases are only defined for subqueries used as tables in a FROM clause.

Comment: There is no EXCEPT in mysql/mariadb search for mysql except to find alternatives. For second query WITH may not be available - what version of mariadb are you on? select version().

Comment: Common Table Expressions were introduced in MariaDB 10.2.1. - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/with/

Comment: version is 5.5.68

Comment: There isn't a mariadb version 5.5.68 likely this is an elderly version of mysql and in mysql common table expression weren't introduced until version 8 - wherever you are getting this code from it's not of much value to you. The use of APPLY makes me think you are trying to lift and drop sql-server code and that just won't work in so many ways because of significant differences in the sql dialects.

Comment: MariaDB 5.5 reached end of life 2 years ago (2020). Are you sure you are using this version? Post the result of `select version()`.